# Resize a single channel in GIMP

Tags: gimp

On a photo taken with a 10mm lens I have some color problems. The red part of the image is slightly bigger then the blue one. Is there a way in GIMP to resize only the red channel?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer:

Colors->Compose->Decompose converts the channels into layers, which can be moved, scaled etc.

Colors->Compose->Recompose to compose the image back.

Comment: Yes - that is the correct way to do it. GIMP can lock paint operations on a per-channel bases, in the "channels" dockable (just toggle the channels you desire to lock - note that visibility toggling and painting toggle are separate things) - so you could just paint on the red channel - but image transforms do ignore this locking.